# android change row items view inside listview related one fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have developed one app base on server connection and download content from server. for informing progress of downloaded files pr in order to change view of row item of one Listview in fragment that contained it I provide some code in my custom Adapter as to keep **convertView** object:

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View convertView = view;
    final MusicDownloadStructure data = getItem(position);

       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_online_store_row_item,
                parent, false);
           data.view = convertView;
       } else {
           data.view = convertView;
       }
     }
```

When run asynctask thread I use this object in order to change view of Listview row items as:

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
        if (mdata.view != null) {
        TextView statusTextView = (TextView) mdata.view
                .findViewById(com.example.app.R.id.tab2_downloadProgressText);
        statusTextView.setText(String.Valueof(values[0]));
    }
```

**problem :**
1-when asynctask execute Textview not change Although onProgressUpdate should be run on UI  thread
2-sometimes that Text of this element started to change other row affect this change! 
anynody can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` :

```
void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
            if (mdata.view != null) {
            TextView statusTextView = (TextView) mdata.view
                    .findViewById(com.example.app.R.id.tab2_downloadProgressText);
            statusTextView.setText(String.Valueof(values[0]));
            myListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); //or simply notifyDataSetChanged if your Async inside adapter
        }
```

Comment: may reduce Optimization or not ?!

Comment: @FxRi4 i dont think so. You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` each time the data value's changed, its the best way to do it. You have 1 more option, by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute` but your list will only be updated when the `asynctask` done (which you might not want)

Comment: @FxRi4 what do you mean?